# Find point on sigmoid curve

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy-optimize

Perhaps a very simple problem, but I can't seem to find an answer that works.

I am plotting a series of values that returns a sigmoid curve below: [image: Sigmoid curve]

The code that was used is (from User88484):

```py
def sigmoid(x, L ,x0, k, b):
    y = L / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))+b
    return (y)

p0 = [max(po_array), np.median(sp_array), 1, min(po_array)]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, sp_array, po_array, p0, method='dogbox')

print("Popt:", popt)
print()
print("Pcov:", pcov)
```

This returns the following values:

> Popt: [96.74093921 12.83580801  0.56406601  3.2468077 ]
>
> Pcov: [[ 4.15866152e-01 -3.57909355e-05 -5.46449590e-03
> -2.10617443e-01]  [-3.57909355e-05  1.81185487e-03 -8.47729461e-06  7.55813943e-03]  [-5.46449590e-03 -8.47729461e-06  1.48370347e-04  2.67572376e-03]  [-2.10617443e-01  7.55813943e-03  2.67572376e-03  1.75321322e-01]]

Given this, how can I find the y value of the curve, when I am given the x value? i.e. if X = 20, what will the y value be for that point on the curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popt` has the fitted values of your defined sigmoid function (`L` ,`x0`, `k` and `b`). Pass them back to `sigmoid`:

```py
sigmoid(20, *popt)
```

The [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for `curve_fit` have something very close to it at the end of the example.

Comment: Thanks, was just coming to say that this worked perfectly without the "x=". If you edit your answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yep tested it myself too. Edited the answer.